# Script xpccachectl not found

Tags: macos-high-sierra, clear-cache

I'm trying to run script to clear cache:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl
```

But system cannot find it with following error:

> sudo: /usr/libexec/xpccachectl: command not found

System: macOS 10.13.2.

Maybe anybody solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The commandline way to install required components is:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode -installComponents